# Microsoft Access Login System & Admin User Level Security

Tags: vba, ms-access

before you ask i have spents weeks googling this to no avail. I am currently designing a database system for a business in Microsoft Access 2007. The system works fine but theres some things i need help with to fix.

Currently, i have 2 forms;

Login_FRM - A form which is a login screen. The code for this box at the moment is

```
If IsNull(Me.Username) Or Me.Username = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter the username of an active employee.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
            Me.Username.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

If IsNull(Me.PasswordLookup) Or Me.PasswordLookup = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must provide a password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
            Me.PasswordLookup.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Me.PasswordLookup.Value = DLookup("[Password]", "User_TBL", "[Username] ='" & Me.Username & "'")

    If Me.PasswordLookup.Value = Me.PasswordLookup.Value Then

    DoCmd.OpenForm "MainMenu_FRM"

    Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Please try again"
        Me.PasswordLookup.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If    
End Sub
```

This checks if null etc, but also checks against fields stored in the User_TBL to see if the user can gain access.

I also have MainMenu_FRM, which is a main springboard for all the processes of the database.

Basically what i want to do is to ONLY allow a user access to an Admin menu, if there are registered as Admin in the User_TBL (Yes/No)

I would be very greatful for any help that anyone has.

Thanks

Here is a quick outline of the whole process

1. User /who is not admin/ is displayed with login screen.
2. User enters details and clicks login, gained access to main menu.
3. Clicks admin button on main menu. Is denied access.

Comment: You understand that this is tissue thin and will only work at all for users with no knowledge of MS Access?

Comment: @Remou What other options do they have if an accdb file is to be used? It seems like login controls like this are more for users not maliciously using the database and kind of for "flow control" rather than any true security.

Comment: @Brad There are no other options with accdb, as far as I know, and as long as the OP is aware that this is just "flow control" that's fine. I'd hate to think that someone thought they could store sensitive information safely in such a set-up.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it may be best to present everyone with a log in screen and then check if they are Admin when they try to access the Admin screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm designing something along the same lines, and I've found it's useful to insert the user permission into a `TempVars()` from the results of the user login. It's only updated from the login, and not anywhere else in the database.

[Info on TempVar from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb257080%28v=office.12%29.aspx), but there is a better description from [the Access Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2010/09/27/power-tip-maximize-the-user-of-tempvars-in-access-2007-and-2010.aspx)

On any button (to open form) intended to have limited access, the onclick event would evaluate the user permission variable. Thus I could have a `MsgBox` if the user was not allowed to use the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is simpler than you think.

Just do an if statement in the form load of the `MainMenu_FRM` that only enables the buttons for admins and set the default so that it's disabled for everyone else. Then only admins can click it.

Why don't admins have to login as well? Just have them login, and set their permissions appropriately after they log in.

i.e. Set every button on `MainMenu_FRM` to `Enabled = no` in properties.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
'****Admin****
If strUserAccess = "Admin" Then
Me.buttonThatTakesYouSomewhere.Enabled = True
Me.buttonThatTakesYouSomewhereElse.Enabled = True


 '****USER****
ElseIf strUserAccess = "User" Then
Me.buttonThatTakesUsersSomewhere.Enabled = True
Me.buttonThatTakesUsersSomewhereElse.Enabled = True
end if

end sub
```

Also, for security reasons, make sure you password your code and disable shift override so nobody can break anything.

Use a DLookup based on their login name (which you can set as a tempvar on the login screen) to find their access level from the table.

per your second part from the comments.
I've never called a temp var in a dlookup, so I can only take a stab at it.
You might need to google how to do it correctly if it doesn't work. It could need more or less quotation marks.

```
dim strUserAccess as String
strUserAccess = DLookup("fieldname", "tablename", "[UserName]="" & TempVars("Username").value  & "")

if strUserAccess = "Admin" then
...
```

and so on.
I may have typoed the Dlookup, and I'm not 100% sure that this will even work, but it should do.

Comment: Protecting the code project is a good idea, however disabling the shift override is **easily** undone, especially in versions later than 2003 whereby **user level security** has gone. I reckon an **Accde** release may be better.

Comment: The system is never actually going to be used, just for a school project, so don't worry about hacking etc

Comment: Thanks seth, i have done that in the main menu form, how do i know implement the second bit into my login screen button? the code is up the top btw ^^^

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I can guess though.

I think you need to add a DLookup for Access level at the top of your form load for your main form, and reference whatever the username is after login from your login screen. The easiest way might be to put a visible but locked text box that shows the users login name at the top of the Main screen, then reference that to get their access level with the dlookup, then set permissions afterwards.

Comment: Not sure how to do that mate, im not that good with vba, I have stored the username and password as tempvars in the LOGIN form 

"Dim Username As TempVars
Dim PasswordLookup As TempVar"

How do i call this in the main menu form?

Comment: I have done that but i get a compile error: Expected: List separator or )  here;

Dim strUserAccess As String
strUserAccess = DLookup("Username", "table", "[UserName]="" & TempVars*HERE*("Username")*HERE*.value  & "")

Comment: You aren't looking up Username on the table, you're looking up their access level on the table. This won't solve your error, but you have a fundamental error with your DLookup. instead of "username", you need "AccessLevel" or whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure what the conventions are for TemVars, but you might need to add another two sets of quotation marks around it "[UserName]="""" & TempVars*HERE*("Username")*HERE*.value & """")

Comment: The access level is a Yes/No field in the User_TBL called "Admin", how would i do this?